# Index Theorem for Regular Infinite-Agent Economies

Tags: consumer-theory

A formulation of the Index theorem states that for a regular economy:
$\sum_{p | z(p) = 0, p_L = 1} index p = +1$
Does this hold for models with uncountably many agents?